# Are questions about games on specific servers on topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, minecraft

I've been playing Skyblock on Hypixel and I've had a few questions that the wiki doesn't seem to answer. Would I be able to ask these questions or questions about any other games on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is the game publicly available for anyone to play?
2. Is it a legitimate (non-pirated) game?

If you can answer "Yes" to both of those questions, then I don't see any problems.